# AgilityJS Add and Remove Event

Tags: javascript

Good morning,
I try these days to make AgilityJS work, and i'm still stuck with these two naturals events : add and remove.

```
(function(window){

var Test = $$({

    model : {},
    view : {
        format : '<div></div>'
    },
    controller : {
        'create' : function(){
            console.log('create');
        },
        'add' : function(){
            console.log('add');
        },
        'remove' : function(){
            console.log('remove');
        }
    }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $$.document.append(Test, '#test');
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('time out');
        $$.document.remove(Test);
    }, 1000);
});
```

})(window);

I've got in my html a div with an id of #test.
Do someone knows how to make them work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This events are not referring to the moment when the object is added to another one (like window) but they are triggered when you insert another agility object inside the one with binds.

The event remove are working just fine but the event add was replaced by events append and prepend in this commit: https://github.com/arturadib/agility/commit/1b2483333dde3f55b3305f2746e4dd6730a1c364

You can see an example of the remove and append events here:
http://jsbin.com/welcome/14942/edit